# selected value tag of Form::model doesn't bind property from Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel and have an issue when trying to bind a property of the Model to selected values of the select tag. I tried to leave the 3rd parameter null because I believe Form Model Binding will automatically take care of it but it doesn't work. Here is what I already tried:

```
   {{$article->tag_list}} // show [1,3]

    //it doesn't work 
   {!! Form::select('tag_list[]', $tags, null , ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'] ) !!}
    -------------

    //it doesn't work as well
    {!! Form::select('tag_list[]', $tags, $article->tag_list  , ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'] ) !!}
    -----------

    //it works
    {!! Form::select('tag_list[]', $tags, [1,3] , ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'] ) !!}
```

In the model I have the `getTagListAttribute()` which works fine.

```
public function getTagListAttribute(){
    return $this->tags->lists('id');
}
```

With Text Input, the form works fine. Btw, I'm using 5.2.1 version. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the missing piece. the `select` function expects an array but `getTagListAttribute()` return an Collection object.

```
public function getTagListAttribute(){
  return $this->tags->lists('id')->all();
}
or I can do this
public function getTagListAttribute(){
  return $this->tags->lists('id')->toArray();
}
```

Comment: If you are in 5.1 `$this->tags->lists('id')` has changed to `$this->tags->lists('id')->all()`.

Comment: Thank you. This was a lifesaver. Someone needs to update this information on the laracast video https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/22

Comment: In laravel 5.3 function lists() is changed to pluck()